# Grails project setup and convention - testing a spring component that is not really a service

Tags: unit-testing, grails, conventions

At first I have to say that I have more background with Spring than grails, and the later convention over configuration is a bit disturbing, when you don't have the cards.

Considering a grails project.

If I have a 'Component' (Spring term for a POJO that will be in the spring context) that is not really a service, but more a part of another object, where should I put it ? In the src/groovy or in grails/services ? 
It is looking like the second option give me more power for writing my tests and since Grails views Service as:

> Services in Grails are the place to put the majority of the logic in
>   your application

I feel like the grails/services dir is a kind of a bag for all Springified beans...

Next question, how can I **unit** test my Component/Service if I need some companions bean in the Spring context for that said Service.
This companions are not services, but rather other components that are mandatory at runtime but for which I can use default implementations.

With spring I can simply use this kind of annotation to create a small context for my tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/simple-job-launcher-context.xml", 
                                    "/jobs/skipSampleJob.xml" })
```

How to do the same with Grails ? 
I want to know if there is a prefered way to create a small Spring context, that can be reused and composed, for the tests as I can do with the **@ContextConfiguration** annotation.

With all the hidden conventions of grails I fear to not use the right way (if one exists) but the lake of clear explanation about them drive me toward direct usage of Spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have RTFM, and the answer was there, a little bit drowned in the middle of the page:
http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/testing.html

**Testing Spring Beans**

> When using TestFor only a subset of the Spring beans available to a
>   running Grails application are available.   If you wish to make
>   additional beans available you can do so with the defineBeans method
>   of GrailsUnitTestMixin:

```
class SimpleController {
    SimpleService simpleService
    def hello() {
        render simpleService.sayHello()
    }
}
void testBeanWiring() {
    defineBeans {
        simpleService(SimpleService)
    }
controller.hello()
assert response.text == "Hello World"
}
```

---

> The controller is auto-wired by Spring just like in a running Grails
>   application.  Autowiring even occurs if you instantiate subsequent
>   instances of the controller:

```
void testAutowiringViaNew() {
    defineBeans {
        simpleService(SimpleService)
    }
def controller1 = new SimpleController()
    def controller2 = new SimpleController()
assert controller1.simpleService != null
    assert controller2.simpleService != null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting it in src/groovy or src/java (depending on implementation language) is a common approach, and works well in my experience.

As far as unit testing goes, if you need a 'companion bean' to do the test, then it's not really a unit test. How about mocking the object? There are several mocking/testing libraries that work with grails - Spock is my personal favorite.

Comment: Just to add to this because it sounds like OP is new to Grails, when you do this, you'll need to define the bean in your `resources.groovy`.  They syntax is just like `ApplicationContext.xml` and is somewhat documented [in the documentation.](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/spring.html)

Comment: Hi GreyBeardGeek, It is true I'm looking for something between unit and integration tests. I want to run them as Unit for many reasons: it is faster and the companions can be default implementations. I'm aware of the resources.groovy, but this is ignored when running unit tests. So I was looking for a way to define 'small local context' scoped for the tests only.